# Postgresql - Distinct On Result

Tags: postgresql, distinct-on

I have already used 'distinct on' in query, but the result is still duplicate.
Can i only get two result from below picture? e.g: row 1 & 4 or 2 & 3, two rows is different in id and serial number.

[image]

Comment: Row 1 & 4 and 2 & 3 are different. How do you think you can get "distinct" on them? They are already distinct.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the SQL query that returned this result

Comment: Well all the rows have different combinations of `id` and `serial_number` so they **are** distinct

Answer (score 0):

Your rows are already distinct. If you meant to be distinct only based on id, then from what row the other values would come from? If it is not important then what you need is a group by on Id and some dummy aggregation on other columns (ie; max(return_document), max(sales_document), max(serial_number)). Or alternatively you could do this:

```
select id,return_document, sales_document, serial_number
from (
select row_number() over (partition by id order by id) as rno, *
from myTable) tmp
where rNo = 1;
```

You are arbitrarily selecting one of the rows per Id. Or with ppostgreSQL's Distinct on:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id) id, return_document, sales_document, serial_number 
FROM myTable;
```

| id | return_document | sales_document | serial_number |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 88687 | RFC-01-2300082 | SO-01-22002077 | R1H-03490 |
| 88688 | RFC-01-2300082 | SO-01-22002077 | R1H-03490 |

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/2XLwmCZk)

EDIT: This would work for this very specific data set, it might not for another (and you only gave this):

```
with umatch as (select *
                from (select id, row_number() over (order by id) rn from (select distinct id from myTable) t1) _t1
                         inner join
                     (select serial_number, row_number() over (order by serial_number) rn
                      from (select distinct serial_number from myTable) t2) _t2 on _t1.rn = _t2.rn)
select t2.*
from umatch t1
         inner join myTable t2 on t1.serial_number = t2.serial_number and t1.id = t2.id;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/k7H4ktXR)

Please next time be clear on what you are asking and supply enough data and desired output as text (people don't like pictures on SO).

Comment: Actually there are only 2 rows, 88687 and 88688, and i want to edit one of them with one of serial number whichever it is, and the another id with another serial number as well. 
Current condition, the serial number of both is null.
Can i do this?

Comment: @AntiMafia, sorry I don't understand what you mean. You get only two rows as in the fiddle.

Comment: Yes, but i need the unique serial number

Comment: @AntiMafia, sorry I don't understand, it is there already. Maybe your data is flawed.

Comment: Yes it is flawed, and i need to fix this, serial number must be unique

id return_document sales_document serial_number
88687 RFC-01-2300082 SO-01-22002077 R1H-03490
88688 RFC-01-2300082 SO-01-22002077 R1H-03502

Comment: @AntiMafia, I edited to add another without being sure what you are after. It is a wild guess and applies to only data you gave (actually you even didn't give any data but a picture:( ).

Comment: @AntiMafia Really you should fix your data before trying to fix your queries

Comment: @Bergi Yes, i am planning to fix my data with this query, because there are too many data i should fix

Comment: @AntiMafia, beware that SQL is only based on the small dataset you provided. It is not applicable to any data. Since you didn't share a larger dataset to see different situations I didn't bother too in creating variations.